# Play!: How do you include a javascript folder? (not just individual files)

Tags: playframework

At the moment, I'm just individually including my javascript files. 
ie

```
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascript/stuff/file.js")'></script>
```

How would you go about including everything in a specific folder? What's the *"Play! way"*?

eg

```
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascript/stuff/*")'></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no such possibility, because of simple reason: including JavaScript to HTML doc should not be done in custom order. Often just `foo.js` need to be included before `bar.js` and you can't force correct order using asterisk.

If you've got typical set of scripts to include in many view/layouts and don't want to traverse each view everytime when ie. version of some js changes (ie. `foo.1.0.0.js` -> `foo.1.2.3.js`, you can just create a [tag](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaTemplateUseCases), which you can later use in any view/layout. ie:

file: `views/tags/typicalSetOfScripts.scala.html`

```
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("foo.js")'></script>
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("bar.js")'></script>
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("etc.js")'></script>
```

So you will be able to use it later in any layout like:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>@title</title>

        <!-- My typical set of scripts -->
        @tags.typicalSetOfScripts()
    </head>
```

Of couurse you will need still add manually changes to the tag file.